# Tikz Edt ignores font definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes

I am drawing in Tikz Edt. However, Tikz Edt does not use the font size and types I define in the Header.

My Code in TeXworks:

```
\documentclass[120pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
% needed for BB
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw] at (0,1) {1};
        \node[draw] at (0,2) {2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For Tikz Edt, I put

```
\documentclass[120pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
% needed for BB
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
```

in the header as prepended code and simply

```
\end{document}
```

as postpended code.

However, in TeXworks and over Latex editors the numbers are huge as they should be in this example (documentclass says 120pt!). But in Tikz Edt they are not. There they are just size 11pt or 12pt.

A week ago it worked in Tikz Edt as I prepared a huge picture in it, but now Tikz Edt and my document look differently. I narrowed the problem down to the point that the font size of the text blocks do not match.

I would be really glad if you could help me!

Kind regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Unfortunately, the TikzEdt project is no more maintained. You can use the application, but I think that if there are bugs or need for new feature, there's no hope :'(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because TikzEdt project is no more maintained and no news here.